# How to get the url of an img to set it as background image of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, preview

I got 3 external images and a div, I need that when I place the mouse over any of the 3 images that image gets to be the backgroundImage of the div and when I mouse out of the div I need the div to get it's original background.

My CodePen

[image]

That's how far I could get but my code only shows the first of the three images and I know it's because of the index 0 but I just don't know how to solve it. Please guys help me out I beg you!

Comment: Please put your code direct into your question as a runnable snippet not as an image - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are always trying to get only first element from array of images in JS file line 6. You should have write it like this instead:

```
let source = previewPic.getAttribute('src');
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use **:hover** to do that

```
.div1:hover{
    background-image : 'url/path'
}

.div2:hover{
    background-image : 'url/path'
}

.div3:hover{
    background-image : 'url/path'
}
```

Comment: This is not changing the background image of the div that is required.